# Regex for private IP addresses

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering how to create a regex that will match all ip addresses that start with 192.168.1.xxx I have been looking online and have not yet been able to find a match. Here is some some sample data that I am trying to match them from.

```
 /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 241 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 239 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 240 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 238 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:53 -0400] "GET /first HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 204 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "POST /JNAP/ HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "POST /JNAP/ HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "-"
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is an easy task.  In fact, you can locate such addresses by doing a simple non-regex search for "192.168.1.".  By the way, you realize that private IPs include everything in "192.168.x.x", right?

Comment: To be fair @TimRoberts Private IP's are `10.0.0.0/8` `172.16.0.0/16` and `192.168.0.0/24`. Title is a tad misleading. Are we looking for a regex to match ANY private address?

Comment: If we are being picky, the ranges are `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Also, checkout https://regexr.com/

`^192\.168\.1\.[0-9]{1,3}$`

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want to match '192.168.1.xxx', then you can use this regex to use this in python specifically: "192\.168\.1\.[0-9]{1,3}".

I personally recommend using [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to get more familiar with regex. You can enter your data and on the left you can look at a cheatsheet to help you learn.

Comment: Thanks i definitely will be using this.

Comment: The question mentions Python but this is not Python syntax - the slashes and 'g' are likely to confuse new users

Comment: You're right, I glossed over that. I updated the answer and tested it in python myself, just in case

Answer (score 0):

I think here its best to use a combination of `regex` to grab any valid IP address from your data, row by row. Then use `ipaddress` to check if the address sits within the network you're looking for.

This will provide much more flexibility in the case you need to check different networks, instead of rewriting the `regex` every single time, you can create an `ip_network` object instead. We could also create multiple networks, and check for existence in all of them.

```
import ipaddress
import re

data =  '''/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 241 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 239 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Light/OpenSans-Light.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 240 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:43 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 238 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:53 -0400] "GET /first HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 204 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "POST /JNAP/ HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "-"
192.168.1.1 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:19:00 -0400] "POST /JNAP/ HTTP/1.1" 404 203 "-" "-"'''

network = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')

# Pattern that matches any valid ipv4 address
pattern = r'^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'

for row in data.split():
    if (ip := re.search(pattern, row)):
        if ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip.group()) in network:
            print(f'{ip.group()} exists in {network}')
```

---

Output

```
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.142 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.1 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.1 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.1 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.1 exists in 192.168.1.0/24
```